# How to send a mail as Lync conversation history through Exchange

Tags: email, exchangewebservices, lync

I've wrote a Lync mobile client by calling service from my UCMA web service.
But I found that the communication between UCMA client won't save converstaion to Exchange.
So when I login at Lync client I cannot see the history
I think EWS provide some method for Lync to store converstaion history to user's mailbox
But I cannot find method to send such mail.
Does any one know how to using EWS to store conversation history?

==================================================================

I found that **ConversationXml.{CA2F170A-A22B-4f0a-B899-93439DEC3FBC}** must be following format to show the history while you double click the conversation history

```
<conversations xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems" minSupportedClientVersion="3.0.0.0">
<conversationXml>
    <imReceived xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems" ts="2015-07-13T16:34:45Z" from="sip:tester@testenv.com" displayName="Tester" firstMessage="true" type="text/html">
        <messageInfo type="text/html" msgid="">&lt;DIV style=&quot;font-size: 10pt;font-family: &apos;Segoe UI&apos;;color: #000000;direction: ltr;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none&quot;&gt;(H)&lt;/DIV&gt;</messageInfo>
    </imReceived>
</conversationXml>
```

Also **PreviewMessage.{55324EE5-74F0-4727-876D-20ED1469CA65}** could assign any string for message preview on conversation history tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lync client uses EWS to Create Items in the users Mailbox (it doesn't send email). Eg to get Lync conversation history you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243707(v=office.14).aspx . To create conversation items you can use something like https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bd7166b7-755e-4ba7-8ea4-d35727c1174c/using-exchange-web-services-api-insert-item-in-conversations-history-folder-in-outlook?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen. I used you sample to create conversation item and see from LYNC client successfully. But the conversation content didn't display. I try to  add conversation Body that I get from other item in conversation folder into this EmailMessage.Body. Still not work. Also could you please explain the meaning after dot at "xxxxx.{2DA4DF04-920D-4b0b-A1D7-5FC9D21857FE}" in your sample?

Comment: I think your referring to the Extended properties unfortunately the conversation XML isn't documented I would suggestion you look at using a MAPI editor like MFCmapi or outlook spy and look at the existing property's on an item that works. What you then need to do is engineer something back from this.

Comment: Thanks Glen! I try to use OutlookSpy to check the extended properties. I found that the GUID is fixed. It won't change. And I also found PreviewMessage.{55324EE5-74F0-4727-876D-20ED1469CA65} is the preview message apprearing on Lync client and ConversationXml.{CA2F170A-A22B-4f0a-B899-93439DEC3FBC} has a specific format to show the history while we click on the conversation history. I'll add these information to my question!